# settings up sunspot solr in production amazon ec2 with rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I think sunspot is super awesome, but I feel like in all the screencasts and descriptions the way to set it up in a production environment is not covered that much. I'd say I'm still fairly new to rails at all, I've deployed my app to amazon ec2 with rubber and so far everything works fine, however, I don't know a starting point of how to set up sunspot for my app. The rake sunspot:solr:start task is only for development, so how would I approach this in production? Would I create a new instance and install sunspot with tomcat on ubuntu,which is what I read in some boards. And how would I make my app then communicate with that instance?
Any advice is greatly appreaciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually was easier than I thought. What made me think it would be difficult was that sunspot_solr was grouped and presented as only for development and not production. However, after installing java runtime on my ec2 instance I was able to perform the simple

```
sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production
```

Sorry, if my question now appears like not well researched and so.

Comment: Hi rails_has_elegance,Have u installed java in ec2 instance by ssh into that?